# Comparing string character by character in Java

Tags: java

How to compare individual character that is stored in a variable in Java?

```
String value = "abaabb";
```

Now how can I know that `abaabb` consist of only `a` and `b` in it and no other characters like `c`, `d`, ...

For this I want a way to compare individual characters in `abaabb`.

Comment: Could you expand a little bit? It's unclear what you want to do. Also, post anything you might have tried along with what went wrong.

Comment: I want to check whether the characters in the string 'aabaabb' are either a or b. For that i want to compare individual characters in the string. That is my question how to do it in java

Comment: Still not clear. Could you edit your question to include: 1. sample input  output 2. code attempts

Comment: @Chandan you might benefit from `for` clause and `.charAt()` method of String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.charAt()` method:

```
String x="aabbbb";
for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
    if(x.charAt(i)=='a' || x.charAt(i)=='b') {
        System.out.println("a or b");    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String#matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) with [Regular Expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
boolean valid = "abaabb".matches("[ab]+");
```

Answer (score -1):

easiest solution:

```
    String value = "abaabb";
    Set<Character> letters = new HashSet<Character>();
    for(int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++){
        letters.add(value.charAt(i));
    }
```

//Edit
@Trincot
In set we collect unique characters in string, then we can build second collection with letters to check if only 'a' and 'b' are present

```
    Set<Character> check = new HashSet<>();
    check.add('a');
    check.add('b');
    letters.removeAll(check);
    System.out.println(letters.isEmpty());
```